# Is GNU tar incremental backup reliable if ext4 is mounted with noatime?

Tags: ext4, tar, incremental-backup, timestamp

My system is running on SSD on top of LVM logical volume, formatted to `ext4`. I'm using `noatime` option at my `fstab` for this partition.
I'm going to do incremental backups of system partition using LVM snapshot feature and GNU tar.

As I see in documentation of GNU tar,

`` Incremental dumps depend crucially on time stamps, so the results are unreliable if you modify a file's time stamps during dumping (e.g., with the `--atime-preserve=replace' option), or if you set the clock backwards. ``

Is it safe to do incremental backup using GNU tar if filesystem is used with `noatime` mount option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--atime-preserve=replace` restores the access times of dumped files after reading, meaning it changes back and forth while `--atime-preserve=system` doesn't set the times at all. Probably only the changing timestamp could cause comparison to fail, while with option `noatime` the access time is not updated at all. Therefore, I'd say it shouldn't cause comparison to give unreliable results.

On the other hand I don't see how *last access time* `atime` affects comparison, as `incremen.c` (GNU tar 1.30) only handles *last data modification time* `mtime` and in `compare.c:212-214` only compares `mtime` with `tar_timespec_cmp()` and then calls `report_difference()` if modification time differs. I just can't find such comparison for other ext4 timestamps anywhere.

Comment: I did not understand the effect of `atime` on an incremental backup comparison. Thank you for clarification.